# function calling a function that has global variables in php

Tags: php, scope, global-variables

I have `helpers.php` file that's been added via `require` in my `index.php`.The `helpers.php` is somewhat like this

```
function one($arg)
{
    //do something
}
    function two($arg)
    {
        global $variable1;
        global $variable2;
        global $flag1;
        global $flag2;
        //dp something
    }
```

my views are generated based on the global flags I have declared in `function two`.
views are something like this

```
if($flag1 && $flag2)
{
    //do something
}
elseif($flag1==false)
{
    //do this
}
elseif($flag2==false)
{
    //do that
}
```

I have `switch` statement that uses these functions in my `index.php` and then render the view accordingly. the snippet is something like this

```
switch($variable)
{
    case "1":
             $data = one($variable);
             two($variable);
             require("../views.php");
             break;
    case "2":
            $data = one($variable);
             two($variable);
             require("../views.php");
             break;
    default:
            //something
            break;
}
```

I am getting the desired output this way but to avoid a lot of copy pastes if I write a function to be called in for my switch statements in `helpers.php` like

```
function three($argument)
{
    $data = one($variable);
    two($variable);
    require("../views.php");
}
```

and then call this function everytime in my switch statement like

```
switch($variable)
    {
        case "1":
                 three($variable);
                 break;
        case "2":
                three($variable);
                 break;
        default:
                //something
                break;
    }
```

Then I get a Notice for undefined `$flag1` and `$flag2` in my views page and I cant understand why and how to solve this issue with keeping `function three` and using it in my `switch` statement.

Comment: If variables are being defined after the file is included the variables might not be available in the function.

Comment: causing the same problem if I declare the variables at top of the helpers file and including the file the first thing in index.php